# Is there any jar file available for java.io.File?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am working on blackberry, I have a `Jar` file `jaudiotagger`, but in blackberry `java.io.File` not available. Is there any `Jar` file available for it?

Comment: It's better to also add what you're trying to accomplish to the question. I'm guessing class loader of some type, which is why you need the java.IO.File.

Comment: Where did you get this jar?  If you just downloaded a pre-built .jar file online, there's a good chance it's been built with a recent JDK.  The BlackBerry Java platform is based on 1.3, so I doubt you'd have any success running your jar anyway.  Obviously, if you included the *source* in your project, and built it using the BlackBerry JDE tools, then it would be fine (with the obvious exception of the missing classes you're asking about).

Comment: I know Paul is a member here, wonder when he'll chime in? But I don't think there is a way that you can use JAudioTagger with blackberry

Answer (score 1):

Usual `java.io.File` Java API does not work on BB.

See BB API documentation for [`javax.microedition.io.Connector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html) and [`javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection`](http://www.developer.nokia.com/document/Java_Developers_Library_v2/GUID-D69FC49D-783E-45CE-80D4-7A9F3EE08B2A/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html).

You will need to do something like:

```
FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///CFCard/newfile.txt");

// If no exception is thrown, then the URI is valid, but the file may or may not exist.
if (!fconn.exists()) fconn.create(); // create the file if it doesn't exist

OutputStream os = fconn.openOutputStream();

//...

fconn.close();
```

Comment: this is FileConnection class, i need object in java.io.File

Comment: you need [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadblackberry500jar.htm) `jar` since `java.io.File` doesn't work on BB.

Comment: I'm not sure what that jar link is, but if you view the contents list, you'll see that it only has `net.rim.device.api.io.File`, which is the RIM `File` class, not the `java.io.File` class.